# Возникли сомнения в грамотности корректора

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, и

Помогите, пожалуйста, разрешить сомнения в грамотности корректуры на примере нескольких предложений.

> Можно бесконечно долго вести научный поиск,**(запятая удалена)**
> только для того, чтобы открыть новые основополагающие принципы в
> науке, вместо того,**(запятая удалена)** чтобы увидеть реально
> существующие. Это то, что для меня очевидно в поисках Пенроуза,
> который пытается,**(запятая удалена)** таким образом,**(запятая
> удалена)** отыскать новый закон физики,**(запятая удалена)** для
> объяснения функционирования сознания».
>
> Так что всё происходящее с нейронами мозга — это как бы «тень»
> истинно важных квантовых процессов, **(запятая удалена)** или
> «операционной редукции» в микротрубках».

В абзаце идет длинный перечень концепций, который завершается словами:

> "...анализ моделей поведения животных и роботов, проведённый
> М.Г. Гаазе-Рапопортом и Д.А. Поспеловым,**(добавлена
> запятая)** и т.д.»

Comment: Просмотрел он лишь отсутствие пробела в «т. д.».

Answer (score 2):

Хороший Вам попался корректор. Вся пунктуация исправлена верно.

Comment: Сердечно благодарю за ответ,не знала, что есть случаи, когда "таким образом" не выделяется запятыми, также вызвала удивление запятая перед и т.д. Что касается удаления запятой перед "или" (вторая цитата), то текст был взят из книги, там запятая стояла. Слава Богам, что компетентные "человеки" еще есть на нашей Земле

Comment: @Ina "Таким образом" здесь не вводная конструкция, а что-то вроде "подобным способом". Конечно, без запятой. Пенроуз не писал по русски :)  А чрезмерно доверять самодельным переводам его книг, выложенным в Интернете, вряд ли стоит, поскольку они не проходят качественной корректуры. Я не профессиональный корректор, но никаких оснований для запятой в этой цитате не вижу.

Comment: grizzly 10,спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, вы мне очень помогли, а то начала плохо думать о человеке, оказалось, что зря, зачет к  вашей карме

Answer (score 0):

Корректор всё правильно сделал.